# TMX crashes in Tablet 10″ Android 7.0 with Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I've developed a video game that has worked fine so far. When testing it in a Samsung Galxy A6 tablet (10" resolution with Android 7.0), I get the following error and the map won't load:

> Blockquote
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369): Process: cam.main, PID: 9369
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion org.anddev.andengine.entity.layer.tiled.tmx.TMXTile.mTextureRegion' on a null object reference
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.entity.layer.tiled.tmx.TMXLayer.drawVertices(TMXLayer.java:220)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.entity.shape.Shape.doDraw(Shape.java:102)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:991)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.entity.shape.Shape.onManagedDraw(Shape.java:120)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:875)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDrawChildren(Entity.java:1008)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onDrawChildren(Entity.java:1000)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:993)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedDraw(Scene.java:233)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:875)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawScene(Engine.java:517)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:509)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(RenderSurfaceView.java:154)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:617)
>   12-09 12:49:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(9369):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:549)
>   12-09 12:49:21.531: E/ApplicationPackageManager(4011): checkSettingsForIconTray value : 0

Rest of screens that are Android native work well. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After losing my faith in Andengine in particular and in game development in general, I found a solution for a problem that seemed to be happening not in Tablets only but **in any device with Android 7 and higher.**

By exporting the tmx files to .xml instead of GZIP compressed everything works well. Almost magic.